# Cannot connect to AWS EC2 Windows Server 2019 instance

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, .net-core, tcp

I am working on a API Server hosted on a Windows Server 2019 instance of AWS EC2 (t2.micro version).  I recently had to update the API after which I have been unable to connect from Chrome on my local machine although I am able to connect locally using http://localhost (it does return a DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID error but if you accept this you can navigate to the website and retrieve the JSON data).

In addition, I am now no longer able to use the VS2019 publish functionality as it returns a ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE (same error is returned when I try to validate the connection).  Finally, if I try to connect via my ReactJS app I get a timeout error.

What I have tried:

- I have checked the EC2 public IP address
- I have checked the username and password (I can use RDP to connect to the same machine)
- I am able to ping the EC2 machine from my local machine
- I have checked the EC2 security groups, it allows TCP 80, 443
- I have attempted connections with the firewall off (and also added exception rules)
- I've run netstat to get what ports are listening (possibly an issue, full file at end)
- I have restarted the machine
- I have stopped and started the machine (updating the public IP address afterwards)

Anyone with any thoughts, been working on this for a number of hours now and no closer.

Thanks.

```
NETSTAT output:

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1801           EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2103           EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2105           EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2107           EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  TermService
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  EventLog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49669          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49673          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:443          EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5357         EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5985         EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8172         EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44363        EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:47001        EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:135               EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:445               EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:1801              EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    [::]:2103              EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    [::]:2105              EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    [::]:2107              EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    [::]:3389              EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  TermService
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49664             EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49665             EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  EventLog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49666             EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49667             EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49668             EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [mqsvc.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49669             EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49673             EC2AMAZ-CFSF2TM:0      LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*                    
  W32Time
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3389           *:*                    
  TermService
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:57259          *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:57258        *:*                    
  iphlpsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:123               *:*                    
  W32Time
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3389              *:*                    
  TermService
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:57260             *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
```

Comment: **Side-note:** A t2.micro instance is rather small for Windows. It only has 1GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks John, yep, definitely a bit small but I'm just using it for a home project and have had it run successfully for a number of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your netstat shows the instance is listening on `127.0.0.1:80`, `127.0.0.1:443` and `127.0.0.1:8172` (aka "localhost") for HTTP, HTTPS and Web deploy respectively. If you look at a working service like RDP its binding to `0.0.0.0:3389` (aka any/all IP's). Thats basically your issue - IIS is not listening on the servers network adapter / localhost is only available, well locally.

You can test this theory by rdp'ing to the server, and trying to connect via your instances public IP instead of localhost. My guess is this will fail, but localhost and 127.0.0.1 will still work. You would also be able to connect to web deploy locally - obviously thats a terrible/pointless idea - but same issue (can use putty or such to make a connection to prove its listening though).

You can just go into IIS and modify the site bindings in IIS Manager snapin- the IP address column should only contain `*` (When editing a binding, set the IP address to "All Unassigned"). I would guess they are currently localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Worth noting in theory IIS should backup its config at each change, so you should have a record of the old configuration in `\windows\sytem32\inetsrv\history\cfgHistory_NNNNNNNNNN` directory

The current IIS config is stored in `inetsrv\config\applicationHosts.config`. You can edit this file directly - **but** i would advise powershell or appcmd as they deals with the quirks of 32/64bit.

If you edit the config directly (stop the w3svc service first) remember to use a 64bit editor (like the builtin notepad.exe) to edit the 64bit config files (dont mess with the contents of SysWOW64\inetsvc - only use System32 even for 64bit files - its the "bitness" of the editor that determines which file Windows will modify)

**NOTE** Messing with applicationHosts.config can break IIS. Make sure you backup first, and i would strongly recommend using Powershell or AppCmd unless you fully understand the 32/64bit quirks (ie you make a change but it appears to be ignored).

See AppCmd (take a look at the backup/restore and the set binding examples) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

Also, if you edit the config, this is the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/

Comment: Thanks for that @MisterSmith.  I checked the binding for the website in IIS but they are all marked as *, I also checked (didn't change) the applicationhosts.config file and it seemed to have a * in that file too but when I run netstat I still get 127.0.0.1:80.  I also ran the extra check you detailed about attempting access on the host machine using the public IP and as predicted that also failed.  Any other thoughts or why IIS is reporting one thing but binding to another?

Comment: Instead of looking through IIS I opened an Admin prompt and did a
netsh http show listen
This showed that http was listening on 127.0.0.1, I deleted this setting and then did a
netsh http add iplisten 0.0.0.0
After that I am able to get to the data on the machine.  Really appreciate your help on this, was losing the will :)